# What does "Vpp" mean in terms of generated and measured waveforms?

Tags: oscilloscope, voltage-measurement, terminology, test-equipment

I'm using a Keysight "EDUX1052G" oscilloscope (with built-in wave generator) to drive a red LED through a 470 ohm resistor.  (I'm taking great care to keep the current draw on the wavegen to a minimum.)

I have configured the wavegen feature to emit a sinusoid wave of 2.00Vpp amplitude with 0.0V DC offset at a frequency of 1.0Hz.  Sure enough the LED does pulse briefly when said wave drives the LED forwards (as expected.)

### Question:

If I connect the scope's channel 1 measurement probe to the positive terminal of the LED and enable the "measurement" features to describe the wave, why does the scope report a Vpp of about 4 volts?

A photo:
[image]

Why does the generated amplitude value differ from the measured value?

Comment: @JRE, thanks for editing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said the reason for the disparity is because the waveform generator is displaying the value assuming a 50 ohm load.

I see that in the screenshot that was posted it actually states that the generator output impedance is 50ohm

Many waveform generators these days have a configuration setting to set the load impedance. If you set it to "Infinite" (or "High Z") the displayed amplitude and the actual amplitude in this scenario would be the same. It doesn't change the actual output impedance, which is still 50 ohm, it just changes the displayed value to minimize confusion. (It may cause more confusion for those of us that are used to dealing with it though).

I don't know which scope model you have but here is an example of the configuration in a Keysight/Agilent 33220 function generator :
[image]

[Agilent 33220A Manual](http://ecelabs.njit.edu/student_resources/33220_user_guide.pdf)

Comment: Thank you.  I found the "High-Z" Output Load setting.  This has solved the problem as stated.  I think that the next thing I need to understand is when to choose "50 Ohms" mode versus high impedance mode".

Comment: @Wossname - it depends upon the nature of the load. At low frequencies (<10MHz), most systems do not attempt to match their impedance to a coax cable and have high input impedance and low output impedances. At higher frrequencies, eg used in video or RF circuits, there will be matching to avoid reflections in cables causing issues. Typical impedances are 50 ohm or 75 ohm for cable tv.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. Your generator out is expecting a 50 Ω load.*

To generate 2.00 V<sub>pp</sub> into a 50 Ω load it will need to generate a 4 V<sub>pp</sub> signal internally.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5O2cz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. A simplified DC version of your circuit.*

The situation is further complicated by the rectifying action of the LED. No current willpass when the voltage goes negative so the scope will read the peak negative voltage.

Comment: Many waveform generators these days have a configuration setting to set the load impedance. If you set it to "Infinite" (or "High") the displayed amplitude and the actual amplitude in this scenario would be the same. It doesn't change the actual output impedance, that is still 50 ohm, it just changes the displayed value to minimize confusion.

Comment: Thanks, @Kevin. I don't have a signal generator in my kit and the ones I last used were analogue!

Comment: @KevinWhite, make that an Answer and have a few points :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that your waveform generator expects a load of \$50\,\Omega\$, and the value shown for its peak-to-peak output is what you would see if you did connect the waveform generator to a \$50\,\Omega\$ load.

But your load has a much higher impedance, so the actual peak-to-peak value of the waveform is about double what the waveform generator predicted.

Comment: Spot on.  The manual says the generator output impedance is 50 ohms.